# Web.config Module .net 3.5 WebProject

Tags: web-config, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-2.0

I want to deploy a module on .net 3.5 like in this thread : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709893.aspx

```
<module name="Module1" assemblyName="Module1" virtualPath="~/Module1">
  <dependencies>
    <dependency module="Shell" />
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

But  is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

the configSections was missing something

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="compositeWeb">
      <section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Configuration.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb"/>     
    </sectionGroup>
```